# Using `map`instead of `apply` inside dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

"Which 4-digit number, multiplied by 4, gives itself reversed?"

Here is an attempt to solve this relatively easy math problem, using R

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

expand.grid(replicate(4, 0:9, simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(Var1 !=0, Var4 !=0) %>%
  transmute(newcol=as.numeric(do.call(paste0,.))) %>%
  filter(newcol<2500) %>% 
  mutate(newcol2=4*newcol) %>% 
  filter(newcol==stri_reverse(newcol2))
```

A second approach was this:

```
expand.grid(replicate(4, 0:9, simplify = FALSE)) %>%
  filter(Var1 !=0, Var4 !=0) %>%
  transmute(newcol=as.numeric(do.call(paste0,.))) %>%
  filter(newcol<2500) %>% 
  mutate(newcol2=4*newcol) %>% 
  filter(newcol==apply(.[c("newcol2")],1,function(x) paste0(floor(x/ 10^(0:(nchar(x) - 1))) %% 10,collapse="")))
```

Can you show me how to use `purrr::map` instead of `apply` in the final step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the last `filter` call to the following.

```
filter(newcol == map(newcol2, ~paste0(floor(./ 10^(0:(nchar(.) - 1))) %% 10, collapse = "")))
```

or this

```
filter(newcol == map_chr(newcol2, ~paste0(floor(./ 10^(0:(nchar(.) - 1))) %% 10, collapse = "")))
```